# Python list of named tuples, replacing attributes

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

Here is some simplified code that I don't understand why it does not work.

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyStruct = namedtuple('MyStruct', 'ThreadInstance ThreadName Mnemonic IpAddr IpGW Status Mode')

Node = MyStruct(None, '', '', '', '',  -1, 0)
NodeDb = []
for id in range(4):
    NodeDb.append(Node)

NodeDb[2]._replace(ThreadName='T2')
NodeDb[2]._replace(Mnemonic='ABCD')
NodeDb[2]._replace(IpAddr='192.0.1.2')
NodeDb[2]._replace(IpGW='192.0.1.3')
NodeDb[2]._replace(Status=0)
NodeDb[2]._replace(Mode=2)

print(NodeDb)
```

Here is the output

```
'>>>
[MyStruct(ThreadInstance=None, ThreadName='', Mnemonic='', IpAddr='', IpGW='', Status=-1, Mode=0),
 MyStruct(ThreadInstance=None, ThreadName='', Mnemonic='', IpAddr='', IpGW='', Status=-1, Mode=0), 
 MyStruct(ThreadInstance=None, ThreadName='', Mnemonic='', IpAddr='', IpGW='', Status=-1, Mode=0), 
 MyStruct(ThreadInstance=None, ThreadName='', Mnemonic='', IpAddr='', IpGW='', Status=-1, Mode=0)]'
```

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: -1: Perfectly awful title.  Doesn't mean a thing.  Not helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_replace` does not do what you think it does. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace):

> somenamedtuple._replace(kwargs)
>
> **Return** a new instance of the named tuple replacing specified fields with new values:

```
>>> p = Point(x=11, y=22)  
>>> p._replace(x=33)  
Point(x=33, y=22)
```

You're calling `_replace` but you never store the new `Node` it returns. The reason it returns a new object instead of altering the object 'in-place' is that `namedtuples` are by definition immutable, i.e. they can't be altered after you created them.

Be aware your `for` loop creates a list of four references to the same `Node`. In this case this isn't really a problem since the objects you are creating are all the same and `namedtuple` is immutable, but in general be aware of this.

So in summary:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyStruct = namedtuple('MyStruct', 'ThreadInstance ThreadName Mnemonic IpAddr IpGW Status Mode')

NodeDb = []
Node = MyStruct(None, '', '', '', '',  -1, 0)
for id in range(4):
    NodeDb.append(Node)

NodeDb[2] = NodeDb[2]._replace(ThreadName='T2',
                               Mnemonic='ABCD',
                               IpAddr='192.0.1.2',
                               IpGW='192.0.1.3',
                               Status=0,
                               Mode=2)

print(NodeDb)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Makes sense now that you pointed out the _replace is a new object.

Comment: @scriptOmate, you're welcome. You can mark the answer as solved if it did in fact answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind each item in that list works like a *pointer* in C parlance. Python variables are always passed and used by *reference*. That is, the way it's written, this is true:

```
assert NodeDb[0] is NodeDb[1] is NodeDb[2] is NodeDb[3] # True
```

I think you want to have a list of separate objects, in which case, you should move `Node = MyStruct(...)` inside your for loop.

Comment: In general you are correct, but it doesn't really matter here because all the objects would be the same and they are immutable. In fact, creating four instances of the same (named)tuple is a waste.